# sparking streaming fails to write to hdfs path

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v with kafka 0.10.x using java 1.8.

```
Dataset<Row> dataSet= sparkSession
                      .readStream()
                      .format("kafka")
                      .option("subscribe", INFO_TOPIC)
                      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
                      .option("enable.auto.commit", false)
                      .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 1000)
                      .option("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
                      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
                      .load();



StreamingQuery query = dataSet.writeStream()
        .format(PARQUET_FORMAT)
        .option("path", parqetFileName)
        .option("checkpointLocation", checkPtLocation)
        .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("15 seconds"))
        .start();



query.awaitTermination();
```

After writing data into my hdfs path (i.e. parqetFileName) it fails with below error.

```
[DataStreamer for file /user/parquet/raw/part-00001-7cba7fa3-a98f-442d-9584-b71085b7cd82-c000.snappy.parquet] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer - Caught exception
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1249)
        at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.closeResponder(DataStreamer.java:980)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.endBlock(DataStreamer.java:630)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:807)
```

What is wrong here and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You must have `streamContext.awaitTermination()` in your code - otherwise application will exit immediately after starting your stream.